# Trying to SUM() column values before grouping in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query and it is working fine. It is giving me unique 'ID' column value, so there are no dublicates.

```
SELECT id
     , force
     , strength
     , direction
     , MAX(created) AS 'created' 
  FROM logforce 
 GROUP 
    BY id DESC 
 ORDER 
    BY `created` DESC
```

It is giving me unique 'ID' column value, so there are no dublicates.

Before 'GROUP BY' the table structure is as fallow...

```
id      Strenght    force   direction

Bike    21          .....   ....
Car     23          .....   ....
Ship    55          .....   ....
Car     12          .....   ....
```

I need to modify the above query so after grouping Strength column values are summed.

```
id      Strenght    force   direction

Bike    21          .....   ....
Car     35          .....   ....
Ship    55          .....   ....
```

I would appriciate some feed back...

Comment: even after you sum strength, you will get an arbitrary force or direction from one of the records for each id.  or if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode is enabled, which is the default in recent mysql versions, you will get an error.  think about it and decide how you want to determine which force and direction to return

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
SELECT id
     , direction
     , SUM(force)
     , SUM(strength)
     , MAX(created) AS 'created' 
  FROM logforce 
 GROUP 
    BY id, direction
 ORDER 
     BY `created` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Moises.